# How can I add two CountUp elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my website Im trying to add two CountUp timers. First is working OK, but with second timer Im having a lot of problem. As Im working with wordpress ID is strange

I allready created code for both timers but as I said, second one doesnt work. I think the problem could be with finding this element...

```
var getID           = $( element ).attr('id');
var getIDCurr       = $( element ).attr('#1523517692376-5f09ae62-8203')

$(element).on( 'inview', function(){

        var numAnim = new CountUp( getID , 0, getCounter, 0, 0, options);
        if (!numAnim.error) {
            numAnim.start();
        } else {
            console.error(numAnim.error);
        }

        var numCurr = new CountUp( getIDCurr , 0, 100, 0, 0, options);
        if (!numCurr.error) {
            numCurr.start();
        } else {
            console.error(numCurr.error);
        }

    } );
```

And HTML

```
<div class="de-sc-milestone__count uk-scrollspy-inview" id="1523517692376-5f09ae62-8203" data-start-counter="323626.20" data-symbol="<span class='de-sc-milestone__symbol'><sup>€</sup></span>" data-symbol-position="suffix" style="">323,626<span class="de-sc-milestone__symbol"><sup>€</sup></span></div>
```

I hope anyone knows the solution...

Comment: The pound sign in (#1523517692376-5f09ae62-8203) isn't helping as there is no attribute that matches. Matter of fact, there is no attribute with the ID without the pound sign also.

Comment: the element attr('id') IS 1523517692376-5f09ae62-8203. In getIDCurr you are trying to get an attribute called #1523517692376-5f09ae62-8203 that does not exist.

Comment: @ imvain2 I tried justb with $('#1523517692376-5f09ae62-8203') but didnt work as well

Comment: What is `element` that you are referring to?

Comment: var element = this

Answer (score -1):

Found solution. I changed

```
var getIDCurr = $( element ).attr('#1523517692376-5f09ae62-8203')
```

to

```
 var getIDCurr = $( element ).id='1523517692376-5f09ae62-8203';
```

Comment: no, that's not how `attr` works. Use: `$(element).attr('id', '#15235...')`. You must specify which attribute to set and with what value. not just value.. jQuery cannot magically know which attribute you wish to set